# Unable to connect to a desktop in same network but different domain

Tags: python, ssh, cygwin, paramiko

I can connect to a PC in the same domain as mine using paramiko client. Cygwin server is running on the remote PC.

```
 ssh.connect('135.24.237.170',username = 'cyg_server',password = 'force')
```

This PC 135.24.237.170 is in a domain named 'lsi-PC' which is same as my laptop.

But, for another PC '135.24.237.190' which is in my network but in a different domain (Domain name is Admin-PC) what should be the code to connect to it? Though cygwin is successfully installed and SSHD is running but still when I connect and try to execute a command it fails. I believe its happening because it is in a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

For the PC in the other domain running ssh daemon, have you tried exporting your domain users and groups?

> Another clue that you need to export is if you get a message like:
>
> Your group is currently "mkpasswd".  This indicates that
>   the /etc/passwd (and possibly /etc/group) files should be rebuilt.
>   See the man pages for mkpasswd and mkgroup then, for example, run
>   mkpasswd -l [-d] > /etc/passwd
>   mkgroup  -l [-d] > /etc/group
>   Note that the -d switch is necessary for domain users.
>   To export domain users:
>
> $ mkpasswd -d >> /etc/passwd
>   To export groups:
>
> $ mkgroup > /etc/group

https://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/ssh-cygwin-and-domain-users/

Also mentioned here: ["Setting up a Cygwin OpenSSH Server for Windows Domains on a TADDM Gateway Server"](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Tivoli%20Application%20Dependency%20Discovery%20Manager/page/Setting%20up%20a%20Cygwin%20OpenSSH%20Server%20for%20Windows%20Domains%20on%20a%20TADDM%20Gateway%20Server)

Then you can try SSHing to the computer in the other domain with a username that looks like DOMAIN_username